# Django complex search with kwargs

Tags: django, search

I am writing a view which searches my models db depending on search fields selected by the user. The basic code is something like:

```
def search(request):
if submit in request.POST:
    ...
    kwargs = {}
    if request.POST['field1']:
       kwargs['field1__icontains'] = request.POST['field1']

    if request.POST['field2']:
       kwargs['field2__icontains'] = request.POST['field2']
    ...
    results_list = Mymodel.objects.filter(**kwargs)
    ...
```

Of course this is fine if my query is all AND statements, but if I need to throw an OR in there - is it possible? For example if I needed `field2__icontains = request.POST['field2']` OR `field3__icontains = request.POST['field2']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build up a `Q()` object instead of a dictionary as you work through your fields. Then you can `and` and `or` as you wish.

```
query = Q()
if request.POST['field1']:
    query &= Q(field1__icontains=request.POST['field1'])
if request.POST['field2'] and request.POST['field3']:
    query &= (Q(field2__icontains=request.POST['field2']) | Q(field3__icontains=request.POST['field3']))
results_list = MyModel.objects.filter(query)
```

Comment: ahh ok. This seems the way to go. Seems like I was obsessed with kwargs ;) Thanks!

Comment: BTW - is there a difference between `&=` and `+=` ?

Comment: `&` is bitwise `and`. `+` is addition. They're not interchangeable, and neither are the `&=` and `+=`

Answer (score 2):

To create an "OR" query you can use Q objects.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: Yes, I have used that for search with a single query field. However, I need to construct the query dynamically based on the user input in multiple fields.